# powershell active directory scripts hanging

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I'm trying to assign some rights in Exchange 2010 using powershell... nothing special

```
[PS] C:>add-mailboxpermission -user "j.doe" -accessrights extendedright -extendedrights ms-exch-store-admin, recieve-as, send-as -identity "mydom\administrator"
```

or, alternately,

```
[PS] c:>add-adpermission -user "mydom\XManager" -accessrights ExtendedRight -extendedrights ms-Exch-Store-Admin, Receive-As, Send-As -identity "mydom\administrator"
```

but in both cases the commands never complete. They never produce errors either, they just hang. Ctrl-c will terminate them but it takes an age.

Anyone know a way of diagnosing this?

Comment: What happens if you use the -whatif parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, never saw your responses.

The problem turned out to be, rather bizarrely, that I had a copy of EMC open in another session which had hung. All exchange powershell scripts just hung until I connected to that session and closed the emc - suddenly the hanging powershell scripts executed.

Strange.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are running this on your client machine using the Exchange 2010 powershell plugin?

You could try running this script on the Exchange 2011 console on the server itself, just to see what happens.